# Postgres 9.3 Foreign table | Not all rows returned from external view

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have two PG databases. On the 1st I have view `v_articles`, on the second DB I have created foreign data table (`ft_articles`) which reads all entries from the foreign data source view `v_articles` (with foreign data wrapper). So far everything worked great, but today I noticed that no all records from the view v_articles are inside this foreign data table. Do you have any suggestions what could cause this kind of behavior. In most cases it works - during the last few months there have been just few records which were not "transferred" from view `v_articles` to `ft_articles`.
Any suggestions where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find temporal solution to fix this problem. On the 1st server I created materialized view `mv_articles`, which reads everything from the standard view `v_articles`. On the 2nd server I read data into foreign table ft_articles all records from materialized view `mv_articles` rather than from `v_articles`.
In this case I have all records in `ft_articles`, but that doesn't answer the question - why there was one record missing in a foreign table when reading from the standard view..